# Type 'string[][]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

Tags: node.js, typescript

Let `tagsUnparsed` be a string like `"a b c d+e+f"`. I need an an array that should be:

`["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]`

Within Typescript I tried this:

```
let tags: string[] = tagsUnparsed.split(' ');
tags = tags.map((tag: string) => {
  return tag.split('+')
});
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'string[][]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I don't see where the `string[][]` comes from. `.map` returns an array, not sure what why there is a type definition error.

Comment: `"a b c d+e+f".split(' ')` -> `["a", "b", "c", "d+e+f"]`. If you further `split` each of the members by `+` you get `["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e", "f"]]`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RegExp (space or plus) as a separator:

```
const tagsUnparsed = "a b c d+e+f"
tagsUnparsed.split(/[ +]/) // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

The error is because of you have array of `space` separated strings and then you split each string by `+`, so you have array of strings or arrays:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d+e+f"]
["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e", "f"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

split returns an array, making map return an array of arrays here. You can simply use `flatMap` instead of `map`, or append `flat()` after `map`.

Comment: adding `flat()` after map like `tags.map(...).flat()` gives me `Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'string[][]'.ts(2339)`

Comment: @mles You need to edit your tsconfig to use modern JavaScript.